# How Can I Write c# code inside ASP tags

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code and I have this error
Code blocks are not supported in this context

```
  <%
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
    %>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="<%=i %>">
        <asp:ListItem><%i.ToString(); %></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <%
        }            
    %>
```

Comment: Are you working on **ASP.NET MVC**??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not allowed in web forms.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Razor, to write such code. Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3razor.aspx) for example.

And here another [blog entry](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx)

Comment: The question is not tagged with asp.net mvc, it's tagged with asp.net. Because of that, your answer is not valid.

Comment: Ok, then I`ll rephrase it into advise to use MVC3 :)